# CSS Filter as a color modifier for one image

Tags: css, hsl

Is it possible to change, with the CSS Filter methods like HueRotate, Saturation, and Brightness, the color of a PNG drawn totally white? Like Photoshop's color overlay effect, but in CSS.

This would be a good solution to avoid creating lots of images that change only color. For example, a set of icons that have dark and light versions for a UI.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: why you pulled my question back to the initial revision? I know my english isn't that much, and the improvemment made by the other guy was really necessary.

Comment: His edit was poor - he added as much damage as he removed. But you're right, I removed some fixes. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks man, I realy appreciate that!

Comment: By the way: really, not realy... sorry, hahaha...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can also colorize white images by adding sepia and then some saturation, hue-rotation, e.g. in CSS:

`filter: sepia() saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(30deg)`

This should make white image as green image.

http://jsbin.com/xetefa/1/edit

Comment: Added a JSBin to show this for each hue-rotate value. It's clear not all colors can be generated unfortunately.

Comment: add brightness(50%) to move in and out of the colour wheel and you should be able to get any colour

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - now if only someone would make an online tool to generate the filter required to get a particular rgb/hsl value...

Comment: This is a really really clever idea - understanding that the `sepia` filter can change a shade to a colour! Great stuff. Agree this should be accepted.

Comment: I've opened a question about the exact formula to go from black to any color here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42966641/181228

Comment: Amazing, and basically all colors can be generated by adding invert

Comment: Apparently, this does work in Chrome but not Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

This is a cool idea, but it will not work with a white image as you suggest. You can do it with a colored image, but not if it's all white. I tried the following in Safari using the webkit version of the CSS filter:

```
<div style="background-color:#FFF; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg); width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
```

But the box stays white. If I switch the color to blue like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#00F; -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg); width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
```

I get a red box. This is because the filter works on the hue value which is not present in white or black.

Comment: Thanks man, that was really elucidative! So, taking blue as start point (or any other color, except absolute black and white), I can get any other color? Including black and white?

Comment: You're welcome. It was fun trying it. You can rotate to any color or make a color black or white by brightness and grayscale.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! Hahahaha... off course, there's limitations to use this technique widely, but when you get a project with a specific target, things like that really help us!

Answer (score 6):

Actually there thankfully is a way!

The main difficulty here as mentioned before is that there is essentially no colour in a greyscale image. Thankfully there is a filter which can pump in some colour!

**`sepia(100%)`**

I have tried the following css style on a solid colour image, whose base color is `#ccc`

```
sepia(100%) contrast(50%) saturate(500%) hue-rotate(423deg)
```

I was able to change the image colour to a lime green.

Enjoy **;)**

Comment: The hue-rotate() filter is intended to go up to `360deg` max because there are 360 degrees in a color wheel. Therefore, the lime green could be represented by `hue-rotate(63deg)` because 423 - 360 = 63.

Answer (score 4):

Try making `brightness` greater than `100%`.  You'll notice the image will start to fade to white as you move farther above `100%`.  The darkness of an image will determine how far from `100%` that you need to move.

```
img {

      -webkit-filter: brightness(1000%);

}
```

Remember that only Google Canary users can see CSS3 Filters and that CSS3 Filters do not affect the image in any other browser.  (thus far at least).

Comment: That looks like a solution, but if you want to work only with black and white and, for this, there's one `filter: grayscale` already. But, if want to cover **all color possibilities**, you need to choose one default color for the icon and manipulate it with `hsl filters`. That's what I'm talking about, and I simply don't know wich is.

Comment: @MateusDuartePoncedeLeon so what you mean is that you would want the option to not only turn an image completely white, but also red?  Using white was probably a bad example choice.

Comment: sure, white was a bad choice to exemplify the solution, but I didn't noticed that, because I really believed that white color was capable to be changed like I want. Thanks for your help!