# How to "tint" image with css

Tags: html, css

I try to tint an image with the background attribute like this:

```css
.image-holder:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s, background 1s;
  background: #EBEFF7;
}

.image-holder {
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s, background 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/fff/000000.png" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ELSF/1047/

But the image is not "tinted" like expected.

On hover it looks like this:

[image]

but I want it to look like this:

[image]

I tried to test some solution I found regarding overlay of images but neither worked in my example.
How do accomplish this in the least complicated manner?

Comment: "But the image is not "tinted" like expected." and what do you expect?

Answer (score 40):

I used some combined filters for tinting an image completely. Tinting is not possible directly (with filters), but you can paint it sepia, adapt saturation and brightness, and get the desired color by using hue-rotate... I think it was something like this ...

```
img {
  filter: sepia(100%) saturate(300%) brightness(70%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

You will need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Very detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960991/4767533.
And here a CodePen from one of the answers, that gives you the CSS filters you need to use, for any hex value : https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp.

Answer (score 34):

Depending on your browser support use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter?v=control), many options at your disposal, caniuse.com looks promising http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter :-

```
filter: blur(5px);
filter: brightness(0.4);
filter: contrast(200%);
filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 20px blue);
filter: grayscale(50%);
filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
filter: invert(75%);
filter: opacity(25%);
filter: saturate(30%);
filter: sepia(60%);
```

Answer (score 22):

Using `:before` selector you can **tint images** with different colors

```css
.image-holder {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative; 
}    
.image-holder:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
.image-holder:hover:before { 
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to adjust your example to my case but it does not really work. http://jsfiddle.net/6ELSF/1049/ I want it to be tinted on hover...

Comment: @Palmi In your fiddle you're not using `opacity` on hover that's why its overlapping image.

Comment: @Pete Again when I try it with my color it is overlapping http://jsfiddle.net/6ELSF/1051/

Comment: @palmi used background color with rgba()

Comment: again @palmi you need to use some opacity - either use an rgba like the previous fiddle or add some `opacity:0.5`

Comment: @Palmi  Try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/6ELSF/1052/)**, you have to make translucent.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekPandey I think your example works best for me

Comment: You can now also use the `mix-blend-mode` property too to have nice effects, like you have with layers in photo editing software now.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using `mix-blend-mode` which currently has [~88% support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_mix-blend-mode). You can use the same markup as before.

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/fff/000000.png" />
</div>
```

But use this css:

```css
div.image-holder {
  transition: background-color .2s;
  width: min-content;
}

div.image-holder:hover {
  background-color: #EBEFF7;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* Blend with parents background: */
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

For this demo you are wanting to tint whites towards your chosen color so you want to use the `multiply` blend mode. If you are wanting to tint blacks then use the `screen` blend mode.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/kaleidawave/pen/YzPZZVo?editors=0100)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the opacity of the parent container changes all children. make a separate div to control your tint. I hammered something together, but the essentials are there.

```css
.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.image-holder img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.tint {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #00f;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.image-holder:hover .tint {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class='tint'></div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a real tint but this is the way I find easier to achieve a color layer over an image. The trick is to use an absolute layer with rgba color over an image. It works perfectly for my general cases.
Have a go!

```css
.mycontainer{
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
}

.overtint {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
  width:100%; height:100%;
}

img{ width:100%;}

a:hover .overtint { 
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.6); 
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="overtint"></div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
  </a>
</div>
```