# css img tint works only when image is not visible (image is covering tint?)

Tags: html, css, hover, tint

This question is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find a solution. I have a profile image which I want to become tinted on hover. As you can see in the snippet, it works, however only when the image isn't visible. It is a local image, so I have intentionally shown an example of the image being there and not being there. Any thoughts?

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.overlay:hover:after  {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<img onclick="sendMessage1()" id="picture1" src="static/images/richie.jpg" class="box overlay">
```

In this snippet, a web image is used to show what I mean.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.overlay:hover:after  {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<img onclick="sendMessage1()" id="picture1" src="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/HBaobb2gkXAlGq-a6K56PeyaLOg=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/clouds-5b6b4e50c9e77c0050491212.jpg" class="box overlay">
```

Comment: Can you please edit your title? It doesn't make much sense at the moment

Comment: What's the problem? It works in your second example. What's wrong with your local image? Inspect it and debug, we can't fix what you can't reproduce in a snippet.

Comment: thanks, im just trying to show that when the image isnt visible (so when it cant be found), it works, but when the image is displayed, you can't see the tint. Ill edit the title, thanks.

Comment: You should not be using ::before/::after on img elements to begin with, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements

Comment: thanks 04fs :) using a div worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a pseudo-element to cover an image.
Place your pseudo-element on a container of your `<img>`.

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938860/how-to-tint-image-with-css) for more ways to do this.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;;
}

.img-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.img-container:hover:after  {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"><img onclick="sendMessage1()" id="picture1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="box overlay"></div>
```

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements) to learn more about `<img>` tags and pseudo-elements.