# How do you simulate the opacity effect on an element without making it transparent?

Tags: css, css-filters

I want a div to have the "grayed out" look that you get with `filter:opacity(0.5)` on a white background, but I don't want to actually make it see-through.  How do I do this?  I know one solution would just be to put another element with a white background behind it, but I'm looking for a simpler solution with just CSS filter effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to explain the math behind the answer of [@codebreaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227073/8620333) and try to provide a generic formula. I will rely on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798480/8620333) where I defined the formula of some filter functions.

We have `f(x) = p*(x - 255/2) + 255/2` for `contrast(p)` and `f(x) = x*p` for `brightness(p)`

To obtain `contrast(p1) brightness(p2)` we mix both functions

```
f(x) = p2*(p1*(x - 255/2) + 255/2)
```

We simplify to

```
f(x) = p1*p2(*x - 127.5) + p2*127.5
```

Now for `opacity(p)` we have <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574620/8620333)</sup>

```
f(x) =  x*p + C*(1 - p)
```

Where `C` is the background color of the image and in your case you considered white so we can replace it by `255` to get

```
f(x) =  x*p + 255*(1 - p) = p*(x - 255) + 255
```

Now we simply want both function (the opacity one and the contrast-brightness one) to be the same thus we can write

```
p1*p2*(x - 127.5) + p2*127.5 = p*(x - 255) + 255
```

For `p=0.5`, `p1=1/3`, `p2=1.5=3/2` we will have

```
1/2*(x - 127.5) + 3/2*127.5 = 1/2*(x - 255) + 255
1/2*x - 127.5/2 + 3/2*127.5 = 1/2*x + 127.5
...
0 = 0
```

This explain the relation between the values you are using. You can also find any other combination of values you want.

For a generic case we can consider:

```
p1*p2*(x - 127.5) + p2*127.5 = p*(x - 255) + 255
x*(p1*p2 - p) + p2*127.5*(1 - p1) + p*255 - 255 = 0
```

We should have `(p1*p2 - p) = 0` and `p2*127.5*(1 - p1) + p*255 - 255 = 0` so we get

```
p1*p2 = p
p2*(1 - p1) = (1 - p)*2
```

and finally

```
p2 = 2 - p
p1 = p/(2 - p)
```

If we consider an opacity of `0.25` we will have:

```
p2 = 1.75
p1 = 1/7
```

```css
img:first-of-type {
  filter: opacity(var(--o,1));
}

img:last-of-type {
  filter: contrast(calc(var(--o,1)/(2 - var(--o,1)))) brightness(calc(2 - var(--o,1)));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
</div>

<div style="--o:0.75">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
</div>

<div style="--o:0.5">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
</div>

<div style="--o:0.25">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
  <img  height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, thanks!  I was hoping someone who understood the math behind this could give me a generic formula.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the contrast to 1/3 and the brightness to 1.5 simulates 0.5 opacity.  In the demo, the second test pattern has opacity 0.5, but when you mouse over it, it changes to the alternative filter, and you can see from the non-overlapping area that the colors are *exactly* the same, at least as far as human eyesight can tell.

I'm not exactly sure what the relationship is here.  If you want to simulate 0.25 opacity, then you might expect that 1/6 contrast and 1.75 brightness would work, and it's close, but there are faint changes.  It's not as exact as it is for 0.5 opacity.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

#img1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#img2 {
  top: 40px;
  left: 84px;
  filter: opacity(0.5);
  
}


#img2:hover {
  filter: contrast(calc(1/3)) brightness(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
<img id="img2" height="126" width="168" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg">
```

Comment: for you second case, it should be 1/7 instead of 1/6. I updated my answer to explain it as well