# Why does 'filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)' turn red into a peachy-pink color?

Tags: css, user-interface, image-processing, colors, css-filters

In CSS, when you apply

> filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)

to an image, the color red turns into peachy-pink.

Why is this, and what can be done to use CSS to invert an image and still have red look like red?

Example:

[image: RGB image normal]

The same image with `filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)` applied:

[image: RGB image inverted and with hue rotated 180 degrees]

---

***Update:***

It was recommended in the initial answer to apply the above filter to the `html` element and then also apply it the image.  The colors still look off.  Here is the result:

[image: RGB image with filter applied to both HTML element and image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand the why we need to perform some math.

If we start with the `invert(1)` (the easiest one) we will use `f(x) = (255 - x)`<sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798480/8620333)</sup>. So
`rgb(255,0,0)` will become `rgb(0,255,255)`

For the `hue-rotate(180deg)` it's more complex. Considering [the specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#feColorMatrixElement) we will get the following matrix:

```
-0.574  1.43  0.144
 0.426  0.43  0.144
 0.426  1.43 -0.856
```

So we will have

```
R' =  -0.574*R  1.43*G  0.144*B = 1.43*255 + 0.144*255 = 401.37
G' =   0.426*R  0.43*G  0.144*B = 0.43*255 + 0.144*255 = 146.37
B' =   0.426*R  1.43*G -0.856*B = 1.43*255 - 0.856*255 = 146.37
```

Then a final color `rgb(255,146.37,146.37)` which is not a red one

```css
html {
  background: rgb(255, 146.37, 146.37)
}
```

---

> what can be done to use CSS to invert an image and still have red look like red?

It depends on what result you want to get considering the other colors but you can add a `staturate()` filter to get back your red color:

```css
img {
 filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(10);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jikdT.png">
```

Again some Math to understand what is happening. From the same specification and after some simplication we will have the following matrix:

```
 7.87  -7.15 -0.72
-2.13   2.85 -0.72
-2.13  -7.15  9.28
```

So

```
 R' =  7.87*R  -7.15*G -0.72*B =  7.87*255 - 7.87*146.37 = bigger than 255
 G' = -2.13*R   2.85*G -0.72*B = -2.13*255 + 2.13*146.37 = negative
 B' = -2.13*R  -7.15*G  9.28*B = -2.13*255 + 2.13*146.37 = negative
```

A final color `rgb(255,0,0)`

Comment: Wow, Temani, that is a truly amazing answer.  Thank you.  I wrote the question for red to keep things simple.  I honestly didn't expect such an incredible answer.  My larger goal is to swap black and white (and anything close to those extremes) while maintaining colour hues.  Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket well, I would say yes but you need to play a lot with filter function and get the math behind to find the perfect combination to your case.

Comment: Do it with JS pixel by pixel :DD