# Applying a color filter to an image with transparency

Tags: css, angular

When an element in the navbar is clicked, I would like it to get tinted in a color parameter I can specify. I have done some trial and error and have found ways to add the color in an overlay, but they apply to the full image, whereas I would like them only to apply on the white color.

i.e. the multiply function in photoshop. The white color in the image gets multiplied with the color specified, while transparent and black would be ignored.

```css
.wrap {
  position:relative;
}

.wrap:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="button button-clear" style="margin: 5px;" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[route]">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img *ngIf="icon!==undefined" [src]=icon>
        </div>
        <a *ngIf="text!==undefined">{{text}}</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Have you looked into CSS filters at all?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell none of the modes seem to give the desired effect, I have not tested all of them. But assuming from what I am trying to do screen, overlay or multiply would be most likely to work. However, they dont and the best result I could get was an image where the black is colored, but not the white.

Comment: You haven't relaly explained *what* effect you are after...perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: To be more clear about it, I am looking for the following result: Image is white and transparent. whereas only the white part of the image gets a color added to its rendering. the transparent/black part of the image stays the way it is. So rgb(1,1,1) + rgb(1, 0, 0) = rgb(1,0,0) on a per pixel basis. If we assume 1 being a full value (read: 255). However, if it would be easier to do this with a black image. It isnt that hard for me to invert my colors and make it work that way.

Comment: A combination of filters is probably required, `sepia` and `hue-rotate` from what I recall. - https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/coloring-white-images-css-filter

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get those filters to create the desired result. Maybe I can do something along these lines with WebGL on a pixel shader? I am already using some webgl for rendering of 3d in my website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/43960991#43960991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple filters

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  filter: 
  brightness(0.5) 
  sepia(1) 
  saturate(10000%)/* currently red */  ;
  }

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  filter: 
  brightness(0.5) 
  sepia(1) saturate(10000%)/* currently red */
  hue-rotate(120deg)/* now it's green */;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://9group.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/mobile-icon-white.png" alt="">

<img src="https://9group.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/mobile-icon-white.png" alt="">

<img src="https://9group.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/mobile-icon-white.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Wow ok. Thanks, thats what I needed. there isn't really a way to give this a color input and run some algorithm to determine what it has to perform to get that color? This 'll work but that would be super nice.

Comment: Well there probably is but you'd need JS...I'm pretty sure that that subject has been asked before.

Comment: Yeah, that question is out of scope. This resolves my current issue, now to look for an algorithm that does this.

Comment: And here it is, I found a way to do it! https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp. Its not my code, but it works. just going to put it here for reference in case anyone would need this coming across this question.