# HTML - style input type "time" - change color of selection

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style the blue rectangles? I need to change the color to orange.

There are some handles to change some style (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002686/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-small-clock-icon-that-comes-with-the-html-input)), but I couldnt find one for those.

[image]

```html
<input class="timeBox" type="time" value="13:30"/>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You may want to look for some libraries which do this

Comment: It's most likely not possible. The used widget es not standardized and depends on the browser or even the operating system. There maybe some browser-specific CSS properties, but it's unlikely.

Comment: I think you can't using css but you can use  widget to do that

Comment: I see example of [mui-timepicker](https://mui.com/components/pickers/) has darkmode, any idea of how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , It is not possible to give the other colors u can give the color to just the outer but inner part is not possible  
[image]

Answer (score 1):

at least you can change the icon indicator with css:

#### Before:

```html
 <input class="timeBox" type="time" value="13:30"/>
```

#### After:

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(3207%) hue-rotate(130deg) brightness(95%) contrast(80%);
}
```

```html
 <input class="timeBox" type="time" value="13:30"/>
```