# Icon color of html5 input date picker

Tags: html, css, sass, datepicker

How can I change the icon color of the native [HTML5 date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) (`<input type="date" />`)?
Is it possible to change the calendar icon color to `HEX: #018bee` or `RGB: (1, 139, 238)`? I saw a post saying that it was possible using filters, but I was unsuccessful.

[image]

Codepen Example:
https://codepen.io/gerisd/pen/VwPzqMy

HTML:

```
 <input type="date" id="deadline" name="deadline" value="2021-01-01" required>
```

CSS:

```
#deadline{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-inline: 5px;
  resize: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #dde2f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #9fa3b1;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  filter: invert(0.8) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(240deg);
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [codepen example?](https://codepen.io)

Comment: is that browser's native date input?

Comment: Ya that's the native date input, I haven't change much to it. Also, I added the codepen example.

Comment: Looks like it's working in the pen. I use this to calculate the filter for specific colors: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: Thanks, that converted to the color closely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of Chrome's calendar icon in HTML Date Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162645/change-color-of-chromes-calendar-icon-in-html-date-input)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using webkit? I found a similar qustion from
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162645/change-color-of-chromes-calendar-icon-in-html-date-input)

try this code from that question maybe:

```
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
filter: invert(1);
```

}