# How can I change the color of the calendar icon with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm having trouble changing the color of the calendar icon on my post. If I have autoprefixes enabled

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

this is my input

```
 <span className="dark:text-dark-text text-xs text-gray-700">
          End Date
        </span>
        <input
          type="datetime-local"
          className="dark:bg-dark-bg mt-1 block w-full rounded border-gray-400 text-sm dark:border-gray-600 dark:text-white"
          value={value.customRangeEnd}
          onChange={onChangeCustomRangeEnd}
        />
      </label>
```

Answer (score 5):

This solved the problem when in darkMode. className="dark:[color-scheme:dark]"

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are searching for how to customize the calendar indicator for an `<input />` element with the `type="date"` at a specific browser. I'm assuming you are using Chrome so, the way to customize that is through the `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` pseudo-element.

You can use `filter` to change opacity, hue-rotation, or even try the `color-scheme` to change that too.

As a suggestion and expecting that your code works on all browsers, you could use some icon/svg and change the color directly, setting the `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` to something like `display: none`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162645/change-color-of-chromes-calendar-icon-in-html-date-input) could help you to understand more about it.

About the usage of Tailwindcss to do it, I think you'll need to add those changes as some kind of ["custom CSS"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles) or something like that.

Comment: yes, this resolved my problem. `className="dark:bg-dark-bg mt-1 block w-full rounded border-gray-400 text-sm dark:border-gray-600 dark:text-white dark:[color-scheme:dark]"`

Comment: Hey! If this solved your problem, could you consider accepting this answer as the answer to your question? :)