# How to create selectable gradient overlay text with a transition using CSS only?

Tags: css

This is what I have so far... it works but text is not selectable on Firefox (works on Safari).

I am very open to discovering a more efficient way of achieving this (if possible) given using `background-clip` and `-webkit-text-fill-color` is a bit of a hack.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fbd6cd;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #fbd6cd,
    #fdc0ee
  );
}
a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  content: "This is a test";
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #f7af9e,
    #fb8fe1
  );
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1><a>This is a test</a></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no ..................

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am trying to add a transition to darken gradient overlay text... using `:after`. Text is selectable in Safari but not in Firefox... I guess because the "real" text is under identical styled `:after` text. Do you have ideas on how to make that text selectable in Firefox?

Comment: better adjust your question to show your real use case instead of having a generic question where the answer is clearly no. I am pretty sure there is a solution for your case.

Comment: I was hoping the answer wasn't clearly no... but I would be happy to either create a new question or edit this one. What do you suggest?

Comment: edit this one ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Done

Comment: a trivial solution is to add `pointer-events: none;` to the ::after element

Comment: also I don't understand the use of the pseudo element here, why not applying the opacity on the element and you are done. why duplicating the text? https://jsfiddle.net/yn0jtcb8/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting! Looks like `pointer-events: none;` when hovered is handled differently on Firefox vs Safari.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I believe the text is semi transparent (`opacity: 0.5;`) in the jsfiddle... in the above example, colors are solid. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Btw `pointer-events: none;` is brilliant. Thanks for sharing that tip.

Comment: it's semi transparent but the visual result is almost the same (if not exactly the same)

Comment: you deleted your question very fast, here is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/43960991

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. I had stumbled upon that answer... but it converts black to any color vs a given color to another. Do you believe this would work for my use case? Trying to make sense of the answer.

Comment: If you want to have a lot of headaches dealing with complex formula then you can. Honestly I don't think it worth all this effort, your initial solution is already doing the job with opacity.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good advice... that rabbit hole is slippery though.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a pseudo element if you're wanting to animate the gradient, especially if you want the original state to be quite similar. Just use filters and transition those instead, then the text remains selectable.

For example:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fbd6cd;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #f7af9e,
    #fb8fe1
  );
  filter: brightness(1.25) saturate(0.9);
  transition: filter 0.5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  filter: brightness(1) saturate(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1><a>This is a test</a></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** you can also just transition opacity, but this approach keeps the text opaque, which allows you to control the text colours better if they're not always going to be on a white background.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Is there a way to find the right `brightness` and `saturate` values to convert `#fbd6cd` to `#f7af9e`?

Comment: This is fine if you [don't care about IE](https://caniuse.com/css-filters), but you shouldn't. Finding the exact brightness / saturate values will probably take some eyeballing. Maybe some wizard has created a tool for it, but I haven't dug around.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to add `text-decoration: underline;`? Somehow when I add this property, the underline is not visible when using gradient overlays.

Comment: I'm assuming you could use an absolutely positioned pseudo element for an underline with the same background-gradient - the filter transition should apply to that also. That method just runs into issues if your links break across multiple lines. Alternatively if you're happy with a plain-colour underline, use the `text-decoration-color` CSS property to set the colour and it will appear.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to have the gradient overlay apply to the underline right?

Comment: If you don't expect these links to ever run over multiple lines (or don't care about how that looks), the pseudo-element underline approach is workable? https://jsfiddle.net/fzn7xwp9/

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only part missing to this answer is a predictable workflow to convert one hex color to another using filters. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960991/4579271) is interesting in this regard.

Comment: No worries. I thought perhaps converting to HSB and checking the differences between the HSB values of two desired hex colours would be an option (since you can use CSS `filter` to adjust HSB values), but the results from a 2 minute test aren't what I'd expect. You may have more luck with some more time...