# Color to CSS Color Filter

Tags: css, filter, colors, generator

I have been trying to filter a **fully white** image to be able to change colors properly by inputting an RGB value and filtering the image to said color.

I have found a relatively good example on [this](https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/), which I could use to manually input it, however I was hoping for a more clean and quick alternative rather than copying their code directly.

I have so far attempted color filtration manually through the [link mentioned earlier](https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/) and attempted to port it over, however it is very lengthy and doesn't work most of the time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're  exactly wanting to do, but if you wanna add an overlay effect with a color you can use:

```
box-shadow: /**height and width**/ inset /**color**/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recolorFilter({
  red,
  green,
  blue,
  alpha = 100,
  r = red / 255,
  g = green / 255,
  b = blue / 255,
  a = alpha / 100,
}) {
  const recolorSvg = RECOLOR_SVG_TEMPLATE
    .replace('R', String(Math.round((r + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000))
    .replace('G', String(Math.round((g + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000))
    .replace('B', String(Math.round((b + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000))
    .replace('A', String(Math.round((a + Number.EPSILON) * 1000) / 1000))
  return `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${recolorSvg}#recolor')`
}

const RECOLOR_SVG_TEMPLATE = `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="recolor">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
        0 0 0 0 R
        0 0 0 0 G
        0 0 0 0 B
        0 0 0 A 0
      "/>
    </filter>
  </svg>
`.replaceAll(/\s*\n\s*/g, '') // Remove unnecessary white-spaces
  .replaceAll(/[RGB]/g, '$& ') // Reinsert spaces between matrix rows

const filter = recolorFilter({r: 0.565, g: 0.792, b: 0.976})

console.log(filter)

document.getElementById('my-image').style.filter = filter
```

```html
<img
  id="my-image"
  src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"
>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880368/5318303

---

Or easier: Use [smart-color NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-color):

```bash
npm i smart-color
```

```js
import recolorFilter from 'smart-color/recolorFilter.js'

const filter = recolorFilter('#90caf9')
// ...
```